# How can i distinguish whether a user has purchased this item or not?

Tags: iphone, ios4, in-app-purchase

I want to sell videos using my iphone app using apples InApp Purchase methodology.

If any user wants to see the video which will be downloaded from my server location, they need to make a payment for it.then only they need to see that video.

Here, i would like to know one thing when a user tabs on a video to watch , i want to open him to watch if he has paid otherwise not.

So how can i distinguish whether the particular user has purchased this item or not?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

you can check always for SKPaymentTransaction once your transaction.transactionState is become SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased, you can save some information for that user so next time if he open the app again the item purchase state would be purchased, but for first time the all item would be in not purchased state.